# Having python plot two different x-axes with different scales

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here's my code so far:

```
QE_ellip_fixed = [-1.04e-3,-1.04e-2,-0.1,-0.76,-2.34,-2.54]
QL_ellip_fixed = [1.77e-4,9.89e-4,-6e-2,-2.9,-4.45,-2.74]
QP_ellip_fixed = [1.26e-3,1.45e-2,0.14,0.98,2.6,2.5]
QE_ellip_varied = [-1.73e-4,-1.73e-3,-1.71e-2,-0.15,-0.86,-3.16]
QL_ellip_varied = [7.57e-5,7.53e-4,5.4e-3,-0.13,-4.15,-7.3]
QP_ellip_varied = [1.41e-3,1.77e-3,2.34e-2,0.22,1.33,3.14]
RHScalls_ellip = [764021,76388,7625,750,63,3]
RHScalls_circ = [629171,62864,6234,577,41,5]
QE_circ_fixed= [-1.26e-4,-1.26e-3,-1.24e-2,-0.11,-0.57,-2.98]
QL_circ_fixed = [-1.32e-4,5.89e-4,1.5e-3,-0.51,0.4,-9.57]
QP_circ_fixed = [1.45e-2,9.25e-3,4.62e-2,0.58,3.5,8.54]
QE_circ_varied = [-1.26e-4,-1.25e-3,-1.24e-2,-0.11,-0.56,-2.13]
QL_circ_varied = [-1.33e-4,5.88e-4,1.69e-3,-0.45,-0.64,-6.58]
QP_circ_varied = [1.45e-2,9.32e-3,5.2e-2,0.55,3.11,13.05]
alp = [1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1]

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(alp,np.abs(QE_ellip_varied),label='$|Q_E|$')
ax1.plot(alp,np.abs(QL_ellip_varied),label='$|Q_L|$')
ax1.plot(alp,np.abs(QP_ellip_varied),label='$|Q_P|$')
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax2.set_xticks([1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1])
ax2.set_xticklabels(RHScalls_ellip)
ax1.set_xscale('log')
plt.yscale('log')
ax1.grid()
ax1.set_xlabel('alpha')
ax1.set_ylabel('Score (unitless)')
ax1.legend()


plt.show()
```

And here's the outputted image:

[image]

I want to have the values on the top axis have ticklabels in line with the grid lines already imposed, as they actually correspond to those gridlines, but I can't seem to make the top axis not behave in this annoying logarithmic way. I've only specified for axis 1 to have a logarithmic scale, but it seems to have applied to axis 2 as well...

Answer (score 0):

it's because the axes share the y-axis, but not the x-axis. The xlimits are different for each..the following worked for me:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax1.set_xscale('log')
ax2.set_xscale('log') #make sure both log
plt.yscale('log')
ax1.plot(alp,np.abs(QE_ellip_varied),label='$|Q_E|$')
ax1.plot(alp,np.abs(QL_ellip_varied),label='$|Q_L|$')
ax1.plot(alp,np.abs(QP_ellip_varied),label='$|Q_P|$')
ax2.set_xlim(ax1.get_xlim()) #make sure same limits
ax2.set_xticks([1e-5,1e-4,1e-3,1e-2,1e-1,1])
ax2.set_xticklabels(RHScalls_ellip)
ax1.grid()
ax1.set_xlabel('alpha')
ax1.set_ylabel('Score (unitless)')
ax1.legend()
```

[image: img]